# How do I make my discord python bot leave a certain server its in with slash commands?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to automatically make my discord bot leave a server if I use a slash command, I would want to make it like /leave {guildID} then it would leave the server if it is in that guild but I suck at coding, I found another thread like this that explained it but that was without slash commands so I tried to implement some of that code to mine. If anyone could help me that would be great but sorry if its to much to ask for.

```
@bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[settings["guildID"]], name="leave", description="makes bot leave a certain server.")
async def leave(self, ctx, *, message=None ):
    guildname: discord.Option(str, "Guild ID", required=True)
    guild_id = message
    guild = await self.client.get_guild(int(guild_id))
    channel = guild.system_channel
    await channel.send("Leaving this server due to misuse!")
    await guild.leave()
```

Comment: You can upgrade to discord version 2.0, and [here in the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=slash#command) is an example of how to use slash commands.

Comment: `from discord import app_commands` is also required if using the above method